# Null port bindings from inspect, the first time. a second time good. why?

Tags: node.js, docker

I'm using https://github.com/apocas/dockerode to manage docker containers from a node.js app and have written the following function:

```
run: function(opts) {
    var self = this;
    return self.createContainer(opts).catch(function(e) {
        return self.pull(opts.Image).then(function(stream) {
            return self.followProgress(stream);
        }).then(function() {
            return self.createContainer(opts);
        });
    }).then(function(o) {
        Bluebird.promisify(o.start, {context: o})();
        return o;
    }).then(function(o) {;
        var inspect = Bluebird.promisify(
            o.inspect, {context: o}
        );
        return inspect();
    });
},
```

which I call like this:

```
bitcoind: function(opts) {
    return this.run({
        name: 'bitcoind',
        Image: 'seegno/bitcoind:latest',
        Env: ['BITCOIN_DATA=/data'],
        Binds: [process.cwd() + '/bitcoind:/data'],
        HostConfig: {
            PortBindings: {
                '8332/tcp': [{ HostPort: '8332' }]
            }
        },
        Cmd: [
            '-server',
            '-rpcuser=' + opts.user,
            '-rpcpassword=' + opts.pass,
            '-printtoconsole'
        ]
    });
},
```

and everything works perfectly, almost. if I start my bitcoind server like this:

```
docker.bitcoind(config.bitcoind).then(function(info) {
    var p = info.NetworkSettings.Ports;
    console.log(p);
});
```

the console shows "null".  the ports didn't get set.  the command line shows me proper values.  running

```
$ docker inspect bitcoind
```

I see:

```
        "Ports": {
            "18332/tcp": null,
            "18333/tcp": null,
            "18444/tcp": null,
            "8332/tcp": [
                {
                    "HostIp": "0.0.0.0",
                    "HostPort": "8332"
                }
            ],
            "8333/tcp": null
        },
```

which is what I expected.  so out of curiosity I then ran:

```
docker.inspect('693f32482b46').then(function(info) {
    console.log(info);
});
```

and that contains the port information!  so I'm puzzled as to why the inspection I ran at the end of the `run()` would return everything but the port mappings.  had I failed to wait correctly for the process to start, inspection would have returned an empty value.

thoughts as to what might be going on here or what I should do differently?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok, the answer is I must wait for the `start` method to complete